# Ubuntu Touch - Unable to delete 5 pictures in on go

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Has anyone come across this issue before, where if you try to delete 5 or more pictures (after selecting them all together), on confirming the delete, the gallery crashed and will close down? I had this happen a few times today.

The funny thing is that you can select 1, 2, 3 and 4 together all OK, but when deleting 5 the gallery bombs out.

Is this a known bug or is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're possibly experiencing this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1589496). This should be fixed with the latest update (v2.9.1.1322).

Comment: It sure sounds like it. The bug says several photos, but I tried 4 and all was ok and then tried 5 and it crashed. I will retest in the new release when we get it. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I have checked the bug report and it is set to released. I have since tested this on 5 and then 6 photos and they were deleted all OK. Closing this down, based on the information provided by pomsky above.